# Time parameters in azure data factory for COPY DATA are not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using the ADF pipeline template "Copy New Files By Last Modified Date" and I have set it up perfectly.

However, i want to set this trigger to run daily and set the LastModified_From as a parameter that starts yesterday and the LastModified_To must equal today.

I have tried everything but it does not seem to be working.

I have tried the following **LastModified_from**:

```
@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), -1, 'Day'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), -1, 'Day'),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

And the **LastModified_to**:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd-MMMM-yyyy')
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

can anyone help me out here please? So the last modified from must be greater then yesterday and the last modified to must equal today.
[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7e7x.png)

I have tried the following **LastModified_from**:

```
@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), -1, 'Day'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), -1, 'Day'),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

And the **LastModified_to**:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd-MMMM-yyyy')
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

..

Comment: Hi. What is the desired behavior and are you getting right now? @B C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to use the dynamic expression in the pipeline parameter.

**The main parameter (pipeline parameter) doesn't support expression or functions.**

To use this expression or function you need to set the variables.

- For **LastModified_from** use below expression to get yesterdays date:

`@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 1, 'Day'),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

[image]

- For **LastModified_to** use below expression to get todays date:\

`@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

[image]

and now use this variable in your pipeline.

Comment: Hello Pratik.
Yes I solved it today as well. The problem is apparently that in the "debug" you can't enter logic/formatting from parameters. 

So I did it like you said, in the parameter itself, and now I fixed it.